# How to properly wrap a c++ library which uses qt with shiboken2?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, shiboken2

I have seen the FAQ https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python#Frequently_Asked_Questions which states

> Take into account that if you want to generate bindings for a Qt/C++
>   project, the linking to the Qt shared libraries will be missing, and
>   you will need to do this by hand. We recommend to build PySide2 from
>   scratch to have everything properly linked.

Suppose you want to use shiboken2 to wrap a c++ library  which itself uses qt and it even uses qt classes in its interface. In the python world you should be able to

```
pip install PySide2 my_cpp_lib
```

and afterwards python scripts shall be able to

```
import my_cpp_lib
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject

my_cool_object = QObject()
my_cpp_lib.my_cool_api(my_cool_object)
```

It is pretty unclear to me how to achieve that setup. From the FAQ I deduce that it would be good to compile PySide2 from source in this case (because I want to use shiboken2_generator to wrap my_cpp_lib). However, I still want to be compatible to the standard PySide2 package (of course there will be a version dependency between my_cpp_lib and PySide2).

Is linking against the QT shared object/dll of PySide2 a bad idea? If so, why? what would be better instead?

If the qt library should be packaged together with the my_cpp_lib python package, then how is it possible to still use PySide without conflicts (because there are essential two different shared objects)?